# Finding Multiple Peaks an Array, Best Algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have this exercise on Code Wars, I have pretty much solved it (I think), but it's not the most *efficient* solution, I can't seem to find the best algorithm to crack it.

> In this kata, you will write a function that returns the positions and the values of the "peaks" (or local maxima) of a numeric array.
>
> For example, the array `arr = [0, 1, 2, 5, 1, 0]` has a peak at position `3` with a value of `5` (since `arr[3]` equals `5`).
>
> The output will be returned as a `Map<String,List<integer>>` with two key-value pairs: `"pos"` and `"peaks"`. If there is no peak in the given array, simply return `{"pos" => [], "peaks" => []}`.
>
> Example: `pickPeaks([3, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3])` should return `{pos: [3, 7], peaks: [6, 3]}` (or equivalent in other languages)
>
> All input arrays will be valid integer arrays (although it could still be empty), so you won't need to validate the input.
>
> The first and last elements of the array will not be considered as peaks (in the context of a mathematical function, we don't know what is after and before and therefore, we don't know if it is a peak or not).
>
> Also, beware of plateaus! `[1, 2, 2, 2, 1]` has a peak while `[1, 2, 2, 2, 3]` does not. In case of a plateau-peak, please only return the position and value of the beginning of the plateau. For example: `pickPeaks([1, 2, 2, 2, 1])` returns `{pos: [1], peaks: [2]}` (or equivalent in other languages)

Here's my solution in Java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class PickPeaks {

  public static Map<String,List<Integer>> getPeaks(int[] arr) {
    
    HashMap<String,List<Integer>> retVal = new HashMap<>(); 
  
    ArrayList<Integer> peakArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> posArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
     Get the size of the Array
    int sizeArr = arr.length;
    System.out.println(" sizeArr >> " + sizeArr); 
    while(sizeArr > 0){
     for ( int index = 1; index < sizeArr; index++){
        if((arr[index]) > (arr[index-1]) && (arr[index+1]) <  (arr[index])){
          System.out.println(" Peak >>> " + arr[index] + "   Position >>> " + index);  
           posArr.add(index);
           peakArr.add(arr[index]); 
        // Dealing with plateaus        
        }else if ((arr[index]) > (arr[index-1]) && (arr[index+1]) ==  (arr[index])){
           posArr.add(index);
           peakArr.add(arr[index]);     
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Pos Array >> "+ posArr +"Peak Array >> " + peakArr);
      retVal.put("pos",posArr);
      retVal.put("peaks",peakArr);

      System.out.println("Retval >> " + retVal.toString());
    }      
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: please specify what do you mean by "efficient" here

Comment: "Get the size..." is a comment. I don't see where your `while` loop ends (for starters).

Comment: You're never changing the value of sizeArr the while loop should run forever assuming the size of the array is > 0 or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> pos=new ArrayList<>();    List<Integer> pea=new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> ma=new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
int cur=0,pre=0;
HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
   for(int a=1;a<arr.length;a++){
     if(arr[a]>arr[cur] ){
     pre=cur;cur=a;
     }else{
     if(arr[a]<arr[cur])
      if(arr[pre]<arr[cur]){
     pos.add(cur);pea.add(arr[cur]);}
     pre=cur;cur=a;
     }

   }
   ma.put("pos",pos);ma.put("peaks",pea);
   return ma;
```